# Remove Models from Collection Being Filtered

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm filtering a Backbone collection by running it through an `_.each()` loop and removing items if they don't fit certain criteria.

For some reason, the loop always stops after filtering about half the collection.

I have two theories:

- I've noticed that the loop always ends on the item positioned last in the collection. Maybe the items are passed to the loop in a random order, but the loop is referencing the "actual" order of the collection.
- By removing items from the same collection being filtered, I'm messing up the loop and it thinks there are fewer items than there actually are.

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/aZ9zJ/. Can someone tell me what's going on?

--

By the way, I know about filtering functions like `_.filter()` and `_.where()` but prefer to avoid them because they return an array rather than a collection.

I'm open to switching over to a filtering function instead, but would still like to understand why the each/remove technique I'm trying doesn't work.

```
App.View.Items = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p',

    initialize: function() {
        Backbone.on('filter:now', this.filterItems, this);

        this.filtered = new Backbone.Collection;

        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            this.filtered.add(item);
        }, this);

        this.filters = new Backbone.Collection([
            {
                property: 'director',
                criteria: 'Orson Welles'
            }
        ]);

        Backbone.trigger('filter:now');
    },

    filterItems: function() {
        this.filters.each(function(filter) {
            this.filtered.each(function(item) {
                if ( item.get(filter.get('property')) === filter.get('criteria') ) {
                    this.filtered.remove(item);
                }
            }, this);
        }, this);

        console.log(this.filtered);
    }

});
```

Unfiltered collection:

```
var itemCollection = new App.Collection.Items([
    {
        title: 'Citizen Kane',
        director: 'Orson Welles'
    },
    {
        title: 'Touch of Evil',
        director: 'Orson Welles'
    },
    {
        title: 'The Third Man',
        director: 'Orson Welles'
    },
    {
        title: 'Jaws',
        director: 'Steven Spielberg'
    },
    {
        title: 'Magnificent Ambersons',
        director: 'Orson Welles'
    }
]);
```

Instantiate view:

```
var itemsView = new App.View.Items({ collection: itemCollection });
```

Comment: Your second theory is the correct one: By removing items from the same collection being filtered, I'm messing up the loop and it thinks there are fewer items than there actually are.

Comment: Thanks nemesv - would be happy to accept as an answer if you have a minute to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By the way, I know about filtering functions like _.filter() and
>   _.where() but prefer to avoid them because they return an array rather than a collection.

But you should use them none the less.

Messing with the collection being filtered changes its length, so the results may be unpredictable. You should `filter` your collection and then `set` the array returned from this operation on your other collection.

```
this.filtered.set( this.collection.filter(function(item) {
            return item.get(filter.get('property')) === filter.get('criteria');
            }
))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aZ9zJ/1/

Comment: Thanks pawel - I really like the approach you took with set()